# How to implement interface or interface-like relation in C++? Confused with .h file and void () = 0

Tags: c++, interface

I have seen the following two implementations in C++, regarding the definition and declaration of classes, which has confused me which to choose, look at this:

```
Class A_Interface 
{
  public : 
  virtual void Show() = 0;
}

Class A : A_Interface // implements class
{
  // implements methods
}
```

But, regardless of this, we have a separation of definition which is like this:

File:

MyClass.h

```
class MyClass
{
   void Show(){};
}
```

And in MyClass.cpp:

```
MyClass::show(){
  /......../
}
```

How the above two differs and are they both some of "interfacing" ?

Because we need an interface to implement our classes against, and it seems both of the above approaches would do that for us.

Comment: Perhaps you should read about abstract base classes and pure virtual functions. There are tons of pages on the Net about this. Also read about C++ in general and header files and such. C++ is not a language you can just jump into and figure out as you go along.

Comment: Proceed with `class MyClass : public A_Interface { ...`

Comment: @dandan If I had considered it as a simple language, I would not have asked this question. I asked it just to know the difference of them from in terms of "interfacing"..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to write an header file, defining the **interface class**:

```
// MyInterface.h -- Header file for MyInterface

#pragma once

class MyInterface
{
public:
    // Empty virtual destructor: good practice for proper cleanup
    virtual ~MyInterface() {}

    // Interface methods are pure virtual:
    virtual void Show() = 0;
    // ... some other methods in the interface...
};
```

Then you can have a **class implementing the aforementioned interface**, with code split between header file and .cpp implementation file:

```
// MyClass.h -- Header file for MyClass

#pragma once

#include "MyInterface.h" // Include interface's header file

class MyClass : public MyInterface
{
public:
    // Methods implemented from MyInterface
    void Show() override;

    // NOTE: "override" is a new C++11 feature.
    // If you are using an older C++98/03 compiler, you can't use it.

    // Other class stuff...
};
```

And you can have the implementation of MyClass in a .cpp file:

```
// MyClass.cpp -- Implementation of MyClass

#include "MyClass.h" // MyClass's header file

// Implementation

void MyClass::Show() 
{
    // ... code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here A_interface is abstract class (an interface) as it has function member that is pure virtual

```
 virtual void Show() = 0;
```

Now consider MyClass; all declarations are in MyClass.h and implementations are in MyClass.cpp (this is preffered approach).

How Both differ?
one is abstract class (cant have object of type A_interface , rather you have to derieve a class from it and overridr its pure virtual function.)
Other is simple class.

Answer (score 1):

When you define one of the class methods to be equal to zero you are making the class an abstract base class and as such it cannot be instantiated (an interface). Some of the methods in the abstract base class can be defined. Although you can't instantiate an object for an abstract base class you can declare pointers to it.

```
Class AbstractClass 
{
  public : 
  virtual void Show() = 0;
}

Class DerivedClass: public AbstractClass
{
  public : 
  virtual void Show() = 0;
}


AbstractClass a = DerivedClass() # FAILS TO COMPILE

AbstractClass* a = new DerivedClass() # WORKS!
```